# What are typical means by which a random number can be generated in an embedded system?

Tags: algorithm, random, embedded, microcontroller

What are typical means by which a random number can be generated in an embedded system? Can you offer advantages and disadvantages for each method, and/or some factors that might make you choose one method over another?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, you have to ask a fundamental question: **do you need unpredictable random numbers**?

For example, cryptography requires unpredictable random numbers. That is, nobody must be able to guess what the next random number will be. This precludes any method that seeds a random number generator from common parameters such as the time: you need a proper source of entropy.

Some applications can live with a non-cryptographic-quality random number generator. For example, if you need to communicate over Ethernet, you need a random number generator for the exponential back-off; statistic randomness is enough for this¹.

### Unpredictable RNG

You need an unpredictable RNG whenever an adversary might try to guess your random numbers and do something bad based on that guess. For example, if you're going to generate a cryptographic key, or use many other kinds of cryptographic algorithms, you need an unpredictable RNG.

An unpredictable RNG is made of two parts: an entropy source, and a pseudo-random number generator.

#### Entropy sources

An [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) source kickstarts the unpredictability. Entropy needs to come from an unpredictable source or a blend of unpredictable sources. The sources don't need to be fully unpredictable, they need to not be fully predictable. Entropy quantifies the amount of unpredictability. Estimating entropy is difficult; look for research papers or evaluations from security professionals.

There are three approaches to generating entropy.

- Your device may include some non-deterministic hardware. Some devices include a dedicated [hardware RNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator) based on physical phenomena such as unstable oscillators, thermal noise, etc. Some devices have sensors which capture somewhat unpredictable values, such as the low-order bits of light or sound sensors.

  Beware that hardware RNG often have precise usage conditions. Most methods require some time after power-up before their output is truly random. Often environmental factors such as extreme temperatures can affect the randomness. Read the RNG's usage notes very carefully. For cryptographic applications, it is generally recommended to make statistical tests the HRNG's output and refuse to operate if these tests fail.

  Never use a hardware RNG directly. The output is rarely fully unpredictable — e.g. each bit may have a 60% probability of being 1, or the probability of two consecutive bits being equal may be only 48%. Use the hardware RNG to seed a PRNG as explained below.
- You can preload a random seed during manufacturing and use that afterwards. Entropy doesn't wear off when you use it²: if you have enough entropy to begin with, you'll have enough entropy during the lifetime of your device. The danger with keeping entropy around is that it must remain confidential: if the entropy pool accidentally leaks, it's toast.
- If your device has a connection to a trusted third party (e.g. a server of yours, or a master node in a sensor network), it can download entropy from that (over a secure channel).

#### Pseudo-random number generator

A [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_number_generator), also called deterministic random bit generator (DRBG), is a deterministic algorithm that generates a sequence of random numbers by transforming an internal state. The state must be seeded with sufficient entropy, after which the PRNG can run practically forever. [Cryptographic-quality PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) algorithms are based on cryptographic primitives; always use a [vetted algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator#Standards) (preferably some well-audited third-party code if available).

The PRNG needs to be seeded with entropy. You can choose to inject entropy once during manufacturing, or at each boot, or periodically, or any combination.

#### Entropy after a reboot

You need to take care that the device doesn't boot twice in the same RNG state: otherwise an observer can repeat the same sequence of RNG calls after a reset and will know the RNG output the second time round. This is an issue for factory-injected entropy (which by definition is always the same) as well as for entropy derived from sensors (which takes time to accumulate).

If possible, save the RNG state to persistent storage. When the device boots, read the RNG state, apply some transformation to it (e.g. by generating one random word), and save the modified state. After this is done, you can start returning random numbers to applications and system services. That way, the device will boot with a different RNG state each time.

If this is not possible, you ned to be very careful. If your device has factory-injected entropy plus a reliable clock, you can mix the clock value into the RNG state to achieve unicity; however, beware that if your device loses power and the clock restarts from some fixed origin (blinking twelve), you'll be in a repeatable state.

Predictable RNG state after a reset or at the first boot is a common problem with embedded devices (and with servers). For example, a [study of RSA public keys](http://arstechnica.com/business/2012/02/crypto-shocker-four-of-every-1000-public-keys-provide-no-security/) showed that many had been generated with insufficient entropy, resulting in many devices generating the same key³.

### Statistical RNG

If you can't achieve a cryptographic quality, you can fall back to a less good RNG. You need to be aware that some applications (including a lot of cryptography) will be impossible.

Any RNG relies on a two-part structure: a unique seed (i.e. an entropy source) and a deterministic algorithm based on that seed.

If you can't gather enough entropy, at least gather as much as possible. In particular, make sure that no two devices start from the same state (this can usually be achieved by mixing the serial number into the RNG seed). If at all possible, arrange for the seed not to repeat after a reset.

The only excuse not to use a cryptographic DRBG is if your device doesn't have enough computing power. In that case, you can fall back to faster algorithm that allow observers to guess some numbers based on the RNG's past or future output. The [Mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) is a popular [choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_number_generator#Generators_based_on_linear_recurrences), but there have been improvements since its invention.

¹  <sub>Even this is debatable: with non-crypto-quality random backoff, another device could cause a denial of service by aligning its retransmission time with yours. But there are other ways to cause a DoS, by transmitting more often.</sub> 
²  <sub>Technically, it does, but only at an astronomical scale.</sub> 
³  <sub>Or at least with one factor in common, which is just as bad.</sub>

Comment: Nice answer.  I assume you would seed the PRNG with the hardwware RNG just once, as opposed to seeding for each RN?

Comment: @ScottSeidman Typically you'd seed the PRNG once at each boot. Sometimes more, for defense in depth: if your HRNG didn't have as much entropy as you'd thought, then maybe your device started by generating not-random-enough numbers, and later injecting more entropy improves the randomness. You can inject as much HRNG output as you want without worsening security (if done correctly, mixing in entropy can only increase entropy); the reason why you wouldn't want to call the HRNG all the time is that it would hurt performance a lot.

Comment: I would like to read more about the possibility of preloading a seed during manufacturing. I have a rough idea how this would be done, but can somebody point me in the right direction how this works?

Comment: @Jesko I don't know what there is to explain in general… It varies a lot depending on the manufacturing process. The basic idea would be that when you install the operating system, you don't install an identical copy on all the devices: you put random content in the file containing the RNG state. But that's a highly simplified view of the process in the best of cases and there's a lot of variation.

Comment: @Gilles I have to clarify: I was looking for more information from a cryptographic perspective, not the technical process. For example, is it cryptographically secure to just seed once (at manufacturing) and is there a recommendation on how much entropy this seed should have?

Comment: @Jesko From a strictly cryptographic perspective, it's fine to seed just once. A seed that's good enough to generate one 128-bit key is good enough to generate random data for the lifetime of the device. From a security perspective, that's another matter: it makes the system completely vulnerable to a leak of the RNG state (e.g. through a read vulnerability that would otherwise be recoverable by feeding more entropy into the RNG state). Some security standards require mandatory periodic reseeding.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to create a Pseudo Random Bit Sequence, just a train of zeros and ones, and read the bottom bits as a number.

PRBS can be generated by tapping bits off a shift register, doing some logic on them, and using that logic to produce the next bit shifted in.  Seed the shift register with any non zero number.  There's a math that tells you which bits you need to tap off of to generate a maximum length sequence (i.e., 2^N-1 numbers for an N-bit shift register).  There are tables out there for 2-tap, 3-tap, and 4-tap implementations.  You can find them if you search on "maximal length shift register sequences" or "linear feedback shift register.

[image]
from: [http://www.markharvey.info/fpga/lfsr/](http://www.markharvey.info/fpga/lfsr/lfsr.html)

[HOROWITZ AND HILL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521370957) gave a great part of a chapter on this.  Most of the math surrounds the nature of the PRBS and not the number you generate with the bit sequence.   There  are some papers out there on the best ways to get a number out of the bit sequence and improving correlation by playing around with masking the bits you use to generate the random number, e.g., Horan and Guinee, Correlation Analysis of Random Number Sequences based on Pseudo Random Binary Sequence Generation, In the Proc. of IEEE ISOC ITW2005 on Coding and Complexity; editor M.J. Dinneen; co-chairs U. Speidel and D. Taylor; pages 82-85

An advantage would be that this can be achieved simply by bitshifting and simple bit logic operations.  A one-liner would do it.  Another advantage is that the math is pretty well understood.  A disadvantage is that this is only pseudorandom, not random.  Also, I don't know much about random numbers, and there might be better ways to do this that I simply don't know about.

How much energy you expend on this would depend on how random you need the number to be.  If I were running a gambling site, and needed random numbers to generate deals, I wouldn't depend on Pseudo Random Bit Sequences.  In those cases, I would probably look into analog noise techniques, maybe Johnson Noise around a big honking resistor or some junction noise on a PN junction, amplify that and sample it.  The advantages of that are that if you get it right, you have a pretty good random number.  The disadvantages are that sometimes you want a pseudorandom number where you can exactly reproduce a sequence by storing a seed.  Also, this uses hardware, which someone must pay for, instead of a line or two of code, which is cheap.  It also uses A/D conversion, which is yet another peripheral to use. Lastly, if you do it wrong -- say make a mistake where 60Hz ends up overwhelming your white noise-- you can get a pretty lousy random number.

Comment: Anecdotally, for my first final project in my 1987 microprocessor course implemented a PRBS on a motorola 68000 (or maybe 68020) educational board.  We had no compiler or assembler.  I had to figure out the Assembler code, look up the hex values, and type them in with a keyboard.  To edit, I could retype if the new code took up the same amount of memory, or fill with NOPs if it were shorter.  If it were longer, the whole code after that needed to be retyped.  We learned to throw in plenty of NOPs!!

Comment: Remembering back now, I think we had to pedal our own generators to power the boards, and if we needed resistors, we had to carve them out of wood with rusty knives.

Comment: Hardware is only half the battle. Hardware RNG tend to have biases, which should be eliminated by passing the output of the HRNG through a software PRNG.

Answer (score 0):

> What are typical means by which a random number can be generated in an embedded system?

Giles indirectly stated this: it depends on the use.

If you are using the generator to drive a simulation, then all you need is a uniform distribution and a [linear congruential generator (LCG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) will work fine.

If you need a ***secure*** generator, then its a trickier problem. I'm side-stepping what it means to be secure, but from 10,000 feet think "wrap it in a cryptographic transformation", like a SHA-1/HMAC or SHA-512/HMAC. There are others ways, like sampling random events, but they may not be viable.

When you need secure random numbers, some low resource devices are notoriously difficult to work with. See, for example, [Mining Your Ps and Qs: Detection of Widespread Weak Keys in Network Devices](https://factorable.net/weakkeys12.extended.pdf) and [Traffic sensor flaw that could allow driver tracking fixed](http://www.csoonline.com/article/2132597/privacy/traffic-sensor-flaw-that-could-allow-driver-tracking-fixed.html). And a caveat for Linux 3.0 kernel users: the kernel removed a couple of entropy sources, so entropy depletion and starvation might have gotten worse. See [Appropriate sources of entropy](https://lwn.net/Articles/283103/) on LWN.

***If*** you have a secure generator, then your problem becomes getting your hands on a good seed (or seeds over time). One of the better methods I have seen for environments that are constrained is ***Hedging***. Hedging was proposed for Virtual Machines where a program could produce the same sequence after a VM reset.

The idea for hedging is to extract the randomness provided by your peer, and use it to keep you secure generator fit. For example, in the case of TLS, there is a `client_random` and a `server_random`. If the device is a server, then it would stir in the `client_random`. If the device is a client, then it would stir in `server_random`.

You can find the two papers of interest that address hedging at:

- [When Good Randomness Goes Bad: Virtual Machine Reset
  Vulnerabilities and Hedging Deployed Cryptography](http://www.isoc.org/isoc/conferences/ndss/10/pdf/15.pdf)
- [When Virtual is Harder than Real: Resource Allocation Challenges in
  Virtual Machine Based IT Environments](http://static.usenix.org/event/hotos05/final_papers/full_papers/garfinkel/garfinkel.pdf)

Using `client_random` and a `server_random` is consistent with Peter Guttman's view on the subject: *["mix every entropy source you can get your hands on into your PRNG, including less-than-perfect ones"](http://lists.randombit.net/pipermail/cryptography/2013-July/004746.html)*. Gutmann is the author of [Engineering Security](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf).

Hedging only solves part of the problem. You will still need to solve other problems, like how to bootstrap the entropy pool, how to regenerate system key pairs when the pool is in a bad state, and how persist the entropy across reboots when there's no filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Although it may not be the most complex or sound method, it can be fun to use external stimuli as your seed for random number generation.  Consider using analogue input from a photodiode, or a thermistor. Even random noise from a floating pin could potentially yield some interesting results.